# Swift - UIPickerView selectRow func not taking array.count

Tags: swift

Im getting strange behavior when I pass in my array.count into my picker.selectRow func as follows:

```
    // savedPhotosArray contains 4 objects
    let num = self.savedPhotosArray.count


     println(num)
     // prints 4

     self.picker.selectRow(num, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
     // picker loads index 0 ????
```

Surley this should work as my savedPhotosArray.count is an Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that the array `count` is out of range of the picker rows.  The count returns 4, which is the number of items in the array.  But arrays start counting at 0, that means the last item in you array (and subsequently in the picker) will have an index of 3.

So if you want this to work you will have to substract 1 from the count:

```
// savedPhotosArray contains 4 objects
let lastIndex = self.savedPhotosArray.count - 1


 println(lastIndex)
 // prints 3

 self.picker.selectRow(lastIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
 // picker loads index 0 ????
```

I believe that the picker loads the index 0 because you're giving it a number out of range.
If you want to check which row is selected programmatically you can use the method `self.picker.selectedRowInComponent(0)`.

If you need more info or this still doesn't work leave a coment.

Comment: Yep that sorted it out. I feel really silly cos i work with arrays a lot and I really should have known this. Many thanks.